# Add php/html file to Wordpress Themes

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am new on wordpress and are using the themes as well. May I know where do I put a new file if let say `main.php`? I want to make a custom main page and replace the `index.php` page on the theme. Do I need to put it under `htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\<theme-name>`. I am using this locally on my computer.

On my `main.php`, I also include css file. Where do I insert the css file as well?

Comment: `How to Create a Custom Page in WordPress ` http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the useful guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set your front page in wordpress dashboard customization options

```
Go to Administration > Settings > Reading panel.
```

and select the page listing in dropdown , but before that you have to create a new page and select you custom page from dropdown . see the below image.

[image]

refer this for more [info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

you can have your css file keep on style directory of your theme and link it in your main page using

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/your-style-file.css'
```

Comment: thanks for the help. For the `get_template_directory_uri()`, do I need to put on the admin page or on my main.php file?

Comment: In your main page , where you want to refer your custom css style file

Comment: Do I need to put this on the main page `is_front_page() ` as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to create page template for this.

Have a look over below thread hope this will help you

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/